# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined @Spring + JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Following is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory2">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.m3.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="M3tables" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.webapp.integration.model.m3" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory1">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="webApp-integration" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.webapp.integration.model.test" />
</bean>
<!-- ##################################### -->

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager1">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager2">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.test.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory1" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
```

In my service file I have added transaction manager in two ways

1 . by adding in class level

```
@Service
@Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
public class MitmasServiceImpl implements MitmasService {
    @Override
    public List<Mitmas> getAllItem() 
    {
        return mitmasRepository.findAll();

    }
}
```

2. By adding transaction in the method level

   ```
   @Service
   public class MitmasServiceImpl implements MitmasService 
   {
       @Override
       @Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
       public List<Mitmas> getAllItem() 
       {
           return mitmasRepository.findAll();

       }
   }
   ```

My full service file is below

```
@Service
@Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
public class MitmasServiceImpl implements MitmasService {

    @Autowired
    private MitmasRepository mitmasRepository ;

    @Override
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
    public Mitmas createItem(Mitmas Mitmas) 
    {
        return mitmasRepository.save(Mitmas);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager2",rollbackFor=ItemNotFound.class)
    public Mitmas deleteItem(String itemNo) throws ItemNotFound 
    {
        Mitmas deleteItem = mitmasRepository.findOne(itemNo);
        if(deleteItem == null)
        {
            throw new ItemNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            mitmasRepository.delete(itemNo);
        }
        return deleteItem;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager2",rollbackFor=ItemNotFound.class)
    public Mitmas updateItem(Mitmas Mitmas) throws ItemNotFound 
    {   
        Mitmas updateItem = mitmasRepository.findOne(Mitmas.getMmitno());

        if(updateItem==null)
        {
            throw new ItemNotFound() ;
        }

        updateItem.setMmitds(Mitmas.getMmitds());
        updateItem.setMmfuds(Mitmas.getMmfuds());

        return updateItem;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager2")
    public List<Mitmas> getAllItem() 
    {
        return mitmasRepository.findAll();

    }


}
```

But I am getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:347)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.leanswift.webapp.services.impl.MitmasServiceImpl.getAllItem(MitmasServiceImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.getAllItem(Unknown Source)
    at com.leanswift.webApp.ui.serviceImpl.DataServiceImpl.returnBeans(DataServiceImpl.java:21)
    at com.leanswift.webApp.ui.presenter.BrowseViewPresenterImpl.returnBeans(BrowseViewPresenterImpl.java:64)
    at com.leanswift.webApp.ui.presenter.BrowseViewPresenterImpl.setBrowseView(BrowseViewPresenterImpl.java:56)
    at com.leanswift.webApp.ui.presenter.LoginPresenter.Login(LoginPresenter.java:46)
    at com.leanswift.webApp.ui.viewImpl.LoginViewImpl$1.buttonClick(LoginViewImpl.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Can anyone help me on this issue

Comment: You somewhere have a `@Transactional` with no value attribute which implies `@Transactional("transactionManager")`. You should have a `BeanCreationException` for whom `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is the root cause

Comment: As an addition you only require a single `<tx:annotation-driven />` basically your first is useless as the second overrides that.

Comment: @orid , i have checked my in service file and its having all methods with @Transactional(value="transactionManager2") . Still throwing the same exception

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the information , but still i am facing issue

Comment: You are using Spring Data JPA and those repositories are annotated with a default `@Transactional`. You will need multiple configrue 2 spring jpa blocks and specify the transaction manager and entity manager to use ( you probably already have one with the entitymanager add the transactionmanager).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have edited my question and I have also added my service file . In my applicationContext.xml file , u can see two persitanceManger configured with two transaction manager .

Comment: As I stated to the different `<jpa:repositories />` elemetns also add the reference to the transaction maanger to use, if you don't it expects the default `transactionManager`.

Comment: @orid  I have added my service file in my question .

Comment: As @M.Deinum stated, add `transaction-manager-ref=transactionManager1` and `transaction-manager-ref=transactionManager2` to your `<jpa:repositories />`(s) tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned you are using Spring Data JPA en multiple `EntityManagerFactory` beans. You need to tell Spring Data JPA which `EntityManagerFactory` and `PlatformTransactionManager` to use for that specific configuration. If you don't specify it tries to use the default `transactionManager`. This is explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.namespace) in the Spring Data JPA reference guide.

> Note that we require a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean named `transactionManager` to be present if no explicit `transaction-manager-ref` is defined.

Your configuration

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.test.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory1" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
```

You only specified the `entity-manager-factory-ref` and not the `transaction-manager-ref`  hence it tries to find a `PlatformTransactionManager` named `transactionManager`.

To fix add the appropriate `transaction-manager-ref` to the elements.

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.test.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory1" 
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager1" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.foo.webapp.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory2" 
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager2" />
```